# Controller Extension Get;Set; and Get();

Tags: controller-extension, url

I do not understand how the get;set; and get(); flow together. I am trying to gather values from a url. I keep getting the Compile Error: Unexpected Token: '='. Furthermore, how would I even test the get;set;? I am lost.

```
public class tablestagingfieldsController {

    public ApexPages.StandardController controller;

    public tablestagingfieldsController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
    }


    public table_staging__c i{get;set;}

    i.name = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('name');
    i.Reservation__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('resid');

    public PageReference saveanddirect() {
    PageReference a = new PageReference('google.com');
    a.setRedirect(true);
    return a;

}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `i.name = ...` and `i.Reservation__c = ...` need to be inside a method or the constructor.

The:

```
public table_staging__c i{get;set;}
```

just automatically provides a `geti()` method and a `seti(...)` method which Visualforce expects to use to access Apex data. See the [Apex Properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm) documentation for a full description.

In a test you can just assign to `i` or from `i` just like you would any other field in the class.

(Better to choose a more meaningful name than `i`.)